# How to tell when during countDownTimer() method a user presses a button?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I Have countDownTimer() method and want to print a certain toast if the user presses the button when the timer is at 10 or 9 seconds left. I am trying to read the time by reading the textview of the timer in the gameButton() method but it only prints the fail toast and not the pass toast. So why can I not do this? And also how can I get it to work? Thanks.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GameScreen extends Activity {

    private TextView time;
    private Button start;
    private Button cancel;
    private Button gameButton;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    private View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.start_ID :
                    start();
                    break;
                case R.id.cancel :
                    cancel();
                    break;
                case R.id.gameButton_ID :
                    gameButton();
                    break;
            }

        }


    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_ID);
        start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        gameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameButton_ID);
        gameButton.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);

    }

    public void start(){
        time.setText("15");
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(15 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millsUntilFinished){
                time.setText("" + millsUntilFinished / 1000);

               /* gameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Perform action on click
                        //if(time.getText() == "10" || time.getText() == "9" ){
                            Toast.makeText(new GameScreen(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //}
                    }
                }); */
            }

            public void onFinish(){
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void cancel(){
        if(countDownTimer != null){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
    }

    private void gameButton(){
        if(time.getText() == "10" || time.getText() == "9" ){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PASS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equals method not == operator

```
 time.getText().equals("10") || time.getText().equals("9")
```

See [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)